# Probability of exactly 2 low rolls in 5 throws of a die

Tags: probability

If a fair die is rolled 5 times what is the probability that the number shown will be less than 3 exactly 2 times.  I have tried to work problem using formula from textbook and still get it wrong

Comment: show us what you have done so far. It is ok at this stage of your MSE journey to type out the equations without using latex (though you should think about using mathjax as a way forward :) ) good luck.

Comment: Hint: On any roll of the dice, the probability of getting a number less than $3$ is $\frac{2}{6}$. Now it is a standard Binomial Distribution problem. One cannot know what went wrong if you do not provide information about what you tried.

Comment: 5!/(5-2)!2!=(10/1)*(3/6)*(2*6)=.100

Comment: Where does the $3/6$ come from?  Remember that $3$ is not less than $3$.  Also, you have to account for the number of occurrences of rolls less than $3$ and at least $3$.

Comment: Then it should be (10/1)*(1/6)*(2/)=

Answer (score 2):

Since there are two possibilities, we use the binomial probability formula

$$\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n - k}$$

where $p$ is the probability of the event, $q = 1 - p$ is the probability of the complement of the event, $n$ is the number of trials, and $k$ is the number of times the event occurs during those $n$ trials.

Here, the probability that the outcome of a roll is less than $3$ is $1/3$ since two of the six outcomes are less than $3$.  That means the probability that a roll will produce an outcome of at least $3$ is $2/3$.  Since we want the probability that exactly $2$ of the five rolls are less than $3$, $n = 5$, $k = 2$, and $n - k = 3$.  Hence, the probability of exactly two rolls with an outcome less than $3$ in five rolls of the die is

$$P = \binom{5}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{5!}{2!3!}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\left(\frac{8}{27}\right) = \frac{5 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 1}\left(\frac{8}{243}\right) = \frac{80}{243}$$

Comment: does the 8/27 come from 2 to the 3rd power and 9 from the 2nd power of 3?  But what about 27.  then the next step is the 5-1=the 4 and the say with the 2.

Comment: Observe that $$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{1^2}{3^2} = \frac{1}{9}$$ and that $$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{2^3}{3^3} = \frac{8}{27}$$ If you are asking about how I simplified the binomial coefficient, $$\binom{5}{2} = \frac{5!}{2!3!} = \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{5 \cdot 4}{2 \cdot 1} = 5 \cdot 2 = 10$$  Note also that $5! = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3!$, so we cancel $3!$ from the numerator and denominator.